# TensorflowJS: web-модель ResNet-50 version of the Faster RCNN ничего не обрабатывает

Tags: tensorflow

Возникла проблема при работе web-модели ResNet-50 version of the Faster RCNN (TensorflowJS)

1. Я выбрал для определения объектов ResNet-50 version of the Faster RCNN pre-trained model ([object detection](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ftensorflow%2Fmodels%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fresearch%2Fobject_detection%2Fg3doc%2Fdetection_model_zoo.md&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNE0V6m_AXFyrl3wM1OLZnou1Ti1fQ))
2. Натренировал эту модель на свои объекты (tensorflow==1.5.0)
3. Сконвертировал

   ```
   Frozen Model (

     tensorflowjs_converter  --input_format=tf_frozen_model 
       --output_node_names='detection_boxes,detection_scores,detection_classes,num_detections'  
       --saved_model_tags=serve frozen_inference_graph.pb  ./web_model

   )
   ```
4. Запустил в браузере. Модель работает 3-5 мин и не выдает вообще никаких результатов. Что я делаю не так?

   ```
   <pre><code>async function loadModel() {
         console.log("model loading..");
         model = await 
       tf.loadFrozenModel('https://mmmaks2004.github.io/
                       recognigetensor/tensorflowjs_model.pb',
                       'https://mmmaks2004.github.io/
                       recognigetensor//weights_manifest.json');
        console.log("model loaded.."); 
   ....


       reader.onload = function (event) {

               image.onload = function (){

                          src_canvas.width  = image.width;
                          src_canvas.height = image.height;
                          src_ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);           
                          var imagedata = src_canvas.toDataURL();
                      let img = tf.fromPixels(src_canvas).asType("float32").expandDims();
                          model.executeAsync({image_tensor: img})
                            .then(function(result){  

                              console.log(result); 

                              detection_boxes = result[0].reshape([result[0].size]).dataSync();
                              detection_scores = result[1].reshape([result[1].size]).dataSync();
                              detection_classes = result[2].reshape([result[2].size]).dataSync();
                              num_detections = result[3].reshape([result[3].size]).dataSync();

                              console.log(num_detections); 
       ...
   ```

   Моя Web Model:https://github.com/mmmaks2004/recognigetensor
5. Может у кого-то есть сконвертированная подобная рабочая модель? Хочу попробовать.